# Blender render is blank

Tags: rendering, camera, eevee-render-engine

so I was making an animation. I have completed the shading, and was rendering. But, the render screen shows up completely blank. How can I fix this?
[image: Layout]

[image: shading]

[image: render screen]

Comment: hello, please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @brockmann No, I have tried that and it didn't work for me. Appreciate your help though.

Comment: The most common issues are listed there. If none of that solves your issue, you'd have to share your blend file (or ideally a minified version) as requested already.